# Know when a sound playing has finished

Tags: android

I am using SoundPool to play some sounds, I would like to know when the current sound has finished, It is possible?

I have very few experience with Java (I prefer Python or C++), and I have thought to set an alarm with the sound duration and handle it. Can I do this in Java?